# Haskell How to print info of some function in haskell like "ghci> :info func"

Tags: haskell

I'm new to haskell.
Sometimes I write some complicated functions that I'm not so sure about the types myself, so I don't define its type beforehand, compiling and running still work fine.
I want to know if I can print out the types of that function like in "ghci> :info someFunc" in the program, just to see how Haskell define its. Maybe something like this:

```
f x = 2*x

main :: IO()
main = do
    print_info f
```

I know I can "ghci> :load program.hs" & then ":info f", but for me it is quite unconvenient & sometime working with ghci can be ugly.

Comment: “Sometimes I write some complicated functions that I'm not so sure about the types myself.” – You're doing it wrong then. Don't write complicated functions, or any functions really, before you've figured out the type. The type is _the basic idea_, it should always be the first aspect of designing a function. That said, what makes perfect sense to use are [Typed Holes](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes), about which you could ask a similar question.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Are you sure that's always the case? Consider the `swing` function: `swing f c a = f ($ a) c`. Pretty simple and clear what it does. But its type is this monstrosity, which is far from simple: `(((a -> b) -> b) -> c -> d) -> c -> a -> d`

Answer (score 2):

Can't be done. You can sort of get close with `Typeable`, but polymorphism cannot be captured, even in principle.

Instead, I recommend that you set up the Haskell Language Server and connect your editor to it; most editors support at least the level of connection that lets you hover a term to see its type or add a type signature to a definition with a keybinding.