# Haskell support for Type Reflection

Tags: haskell, types, reflection

Does Haskell support type reflection as in other languages such as Python?

This is different from [Haskell How to print info of some function in haskell like "ghci> :info func"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72894027/haskell-how-to-print-info-of-some-function-in-haskell-like-ghci-info-func)

Comment: What are you asking exactly? What's the use case for this? Template Haskell has reification if you're just using it for macros.

Comment: Type cheking at runtime is something that is supported in languages like Java or C# but in Haskell this isn't necessary cause it is a strong typed languange. If you need to support more type for a function let's say you can use polymorphic type checking.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `Typeable`, `typeOf`, `eqT` and friends? Or perhaps just type classes? Hard to tell. Can you write some pseudo code showing how you would exploit the ability of "getting type programmatically" to achieve something?

Comment: Unless you've planned for type sniffing with `Typeable` et al, the type doesn't *exist* at runtime. Once type-checking is complete, types are erased, and at runtime the only "type" that exists is basically raw bits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to be clear, all of the special commands in GHCi that begin with a colon (like `:type`, `:info`, etc) are not part of the Haskell language. GHCi supports them by "wrapping around" actual Haskell, and keeping track of extra information. So none of those features are going to be accessible in Haskell itself. If there's something in Haskell that can meet a similar goal, we'll need to look for it in a totally different place.

#### Type erasure

Haskell is designed to have types completely erased during compilation.

Say we have a value like `Just True`. When compiling Haskell *source* code, we know that is of type `Maybe Bool`. But when turned into actual machine code, the code that produces that value will just allocate a little block of memory, with a small number and a pointer to the `True` value. The number is used to tell whether the constructor was `Nothing` or `Just`. All the code that handles `Maybe` values will have been compiled so that it uses the small number to tell whether it should take the branch for the `Nothing` constructor or the `Just` constructor; say the compiler chooses `0` for `Nothing` and `1` for `Just`.

But there's nothing in that little block of memory that says that this is a value from the `Maybe` data type, nor that the pointer is to a value of type `Bool`. Any other single-argument constructor will *also* be represented in memory as basically just a small number and a pointer, and some of them might even use the same number `1` that was being used for `Just`. The number tags only need to distinguish other constructors from the same type; there's no global registry assigning unique numbers to ensure that different types don't use the same numbers.

So it actually isn't possible for compiled Haskell code to look at an arbitrary value and tell you what type it is. That information is just gone.

#### Reflection

Haskell *does* support runtime reflection of types. But it's not available for just any value with no preparation; it's an **opt-in** system requiring you to explicitly prepare for wanting access to type information at runtime. Effectively it uses the type class system to ask the compiler to preserve information about types.

The [`Typeable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Type-Reflection.html#t:Typeable) class is specially supported by the compiler. It is the class of types that can be represented and inspected at runtime. The class actually includes every type; the compiler automatically makes the instances for you. Putting a `Typeable` constraint on your function means that the compiler will make the `Typeable` methods available to you, keeping enough information available at runtime that you can ask "what is the type of this value?". If you don't have a `Typeable` constraint on a type variable, then that information isn't kept available at runtime and you can't ask for the type. (This also means that the `Typeable` constraints need to be added to every function up the call stack until the point where the type variable was actually instantiated with a concrete type; if your callers haven't opted-in to runtime type reflection, then you can't unilaterally get it back)

The way you actually use it is that you can use `typeOf x` to produce a value of type `TypeRep a` (where `a` is the type of `x`). e.g. `typeOf True` gives you a `TypeRep Bool`, and `typeOf (Just 'a')` gives you a `TypeRep (Maybe Char)`, etc. If you need to use this you probably don't know what the type variable `a` actually is, but you can then use `eqTypeRep` to test whether your `TypeRep` is equal to the `TypeRep` of some other known type, and if it is you now know that `x` is of that type and can call other functions on it that are specific to that type. You can't simply use basic `==` tests to test if it's equal to a known type since that only gives you `True` or `False`, which don't prove anything to the compiler; it needs to look a little more complicated, but basically boils down to this simple idea. It could look something like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GHC2021, GADTs #-}

import Type.Reflection ( Typeable, typeOf, typeRep, eqTypeRep, (:~~:) (HRefl) )

foo :: Typeable a => a -> Integer
foo x = case typeOf x `eqTypeRep` typeRep @Integer of
  Just HRefl -> x + 17
  Nothing -> 0
```

Inside the `Just HRefl` arm of the `case`, the compiler knows that `x` is of type `Integer`, so it's valid to add `17` and to return that as the result of the function (which must be something of type `Integer`). In the `Nothing` arm the compiler will not allow you to use `Integer` functionality on `x` or return it, so we have to return something else we know is an `Integer` instead.

The rest of the functionality in the [`Type.Reflection`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Type-Reflection.html) allows you to do some more flexible inspections (e.g. you could test whether a value's type is `Maybe` applied to something, without caring about what type it's applied to). But ultimately it boils down to this ability to take a value whose type is a type variable and make a finite number of "guesses" about its type. If any of your guesses is correct you can act on that information, but there will always be the possibility that it isn't any of the types you're specifically checking for and you still have to have a branch where it's just a black box value (though you can always `error` out if you don't care about your function being total).

This circumvents the normal restrictions on values whose type is a variable; without `Typeable` you can't do anything at all with it other than pass it on to something else expecting a value of the same type variable (such as a matching function that's been passed in, or a type class constrained function if you have available constraints on the variable).

#### Polymorphism

One thing that might not have been obvious from the above is that we can't reflect polymorphism. That is, there's no way to get a `TypeRep` that itself reflect a type containing variables. If a function takes a `[a]` that `a` type variable will be instantiated on each call to some particular type, and the `TypeRep` will end up reflecting the particular type that was used in this particular call (like `[Integer]` or `[Maybe Bool]` or `[Char -> Maybe (IO String)]`; it will not reflect the polymorphic type `[a]`.

#### A word of warning

A large amount of Haskell's usefulness for programming actually comes from the *restrictions* on what you can do with values whose types contain variables. When you get used to it, knowing what a function *can't* do based purely on its type is very powerful.

That goes completely out the window when there are `Typeable` constraints. When calling such a function, you can't deduce anything about what it can or can't do with values of the `Typeable`-constrained type, because you have no idea what types it knows about internally.

As a trivial example, it's often said of the function `id :: a -> a` that we can tell exactly what it does just from its type, because the *only* possible (total) implementation of a function with type `a -> a` is to return its argument unchanged. But if its type were instead `Typeable a => a -> a`, we could tell very little about what it does. For example, this is valid:

```
fakeId :: Typeable a => a -> a
fakeId x = case typeOf x `eqTypeRep` typeRep @Bool of
  Just HRefl -> not x
  Nothing -> x
```

`fakeId` returns *most* arguments unchanged, but if it receives a `Bool` it negates it. And there's no way to tell from the outside that it's checking for `Bool`s and doing something different with them; it could just as well have a huge list of types with special behaviour. If we're testing what it does to see if it meets our requirements, there's no guarantee that we'll find all the types for which it has special behaviour, so we could easily end up with a bug in our final program.

So while Haskell has this reflection system, it really should not be part of your "standard" toolkit. An API where you have large numbers of functions with `Typeable` constraints is almost certainly a bad API; we *want* the restrictions that come with type erasure. 99% of the things you need to do can and should be done without reflection.

Comment: Minor note: ``typeOf x `eqTypeRep` typeRep @Integer`` could also be simplified to `eqT @a @Integer` provided we add an explicit `forall a.` in the type signature. Still, the shorter variant makes it less clear that we are using the type of `x`.